# Is there any way I can change the domain of a function from N to the set of R, it is a function of e with a summation sign as its exponent

Tags: functions, summation

[image]

Is there any way I can replace the summation sign in the equation given in the image and hence change its domain from the set of natural numbers to the set of real numbers?

Comment: The second sum seems to run from $n=1$ to $n=n$.  What does that mean?  You should be using a different sum variable.  The first sum runs from $r=1$ to what?  If the sum is to infinity it diverges.  Please fix the question to be meaningful.

Comment: n is the input while the first sum is from r=1 to infinity.

Comment: As I said before, if the $r$ sum goes to infinity, it diverges, so the function is not well defined even for natural numbers.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a function with any domain, let alone the naturals.  The sum over $r$ diverges as $\frac {n^{2r}}{r^2}$.

If you have a well defined function, there are various things you can do.  The simplest is linear interpolation.  Say you have $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt i$ (Note how I used $i$ for the sum variable to avoid confusion).  We can find $f(1)=1, f(2)=1+\sqrt 2$.  If you want to define $f$ between there, you can do linear interpolation and say $f(x)=1+(\sqrt 2-1)(x-1)$ for $f \in [1,2]$  There are other interpolation schemes that match the function at more points.  They are described in any numerical analysis text.